# Quotient of $\left({\mathbb R^n} \right)^N $ by $S_N$

Tags: general-topology

I am reading a physics [paper](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/BF02727953.pdf).
On the page 6, they claim
$$\left({\mathbb R^n} \right)^N / S_N \simeq \mathbb R^n \times r(n, N)$$
for some space $r(n, N)$, where the permutation group $S_N$ acts on $\left({\mathbb R^n} \right)^N$ as
$$ \sigma(y_1, y_2, \cdots, y_N) = (y_{\sigma(1)}, y_{\sigma(2)}, \cdots, y_{\sigma(N)}).$$

They furthermore claims
$$r(n, 2) - O = (0, \infty) \times \mathbb P \mathbb R^{n-1}.$$

How can show these identities?
Are there some mathematical reference for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define an isomorphism $(\mathbb{R}^n)^N \simeq \mathbb{R}^n \times (\mathbb{R}^n)^{N}_0$. The subscript here is to indicate that the sum of all $N$ factors is $0$.

$$
f (y_1 \cdots y_N ) = ( \frac{y_1 + \cdots + y_N}{N} , y_1 - \bar{y} , \cdots y_N - \bar{y} )
$$

The $S_N$ acts trivially on the first factor. This gives the $\mathbb{R}^n$ on the RHS. $r(n,N) \equiv (\mathbb{R}^n)^{N}_0 / S_N$.

For the particular example of $N=2$. This is two points in $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that their sum is $0$ modulo switching them. So they can both be $0$ which gives a single point $O$. If they are not the same point, then they are some $r \in (0,\infty)$ apart and the vector that points from one to the other gives some $p \in S^{n-1}$. But because we can switch the two points we have to quotient by the $\mathbb{Z}_2$ action that swaps antipodes. That is the $\mathbb{RP}^{n-1}$.

Comment: Very quick and very clear answer!